# Таблица измерения (Dimension Table) из нормализованной таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, моделирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать измерение "Business Partner" из следующих нормализованных таблиц?
[image: Bus Partn]
Таблица Business Partner содержит только уникальные значения.

Табл. InvolvedInsPartnerRole содержит 10-15 уникальных значений: Broker, Parent Broker, Original Insured, ...

Отношения между таблицами 1:n.

Чтобы получить в одном  отчете и Broker и  Parent Broker и Original Insured приходится использовать selfjoin, т.е. джойнить одну и туже таблицу несколько раз. Но в star schema  как я понимаю такое не используется. Отсюда вопрос, как лучше построить измерение Business Partner, чтобы не приходилось присоединять одну и туже табл. много раз.

Большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Начните с подробного описания, что имеете и что с чем и как связано. Сдаётся мне, что показанная схема просто неверна, ибо не соответствует предметной области.

Comment: @Akina: схему поправил.

Comment: А где подробное описание предметной области? того, что именно моделирует эта БД... С чего Вы взяли, что схема нормализована правильно и адекватно? Как правило, M:N:K adjacent table - это следствие логической ошибки анализа. Да, схема схемой, но лучше будет, если эта схема дополнится `CREATE TABLE`-скриптами всех таблиц.

Comment: Это БД одной страховой фирмы, всего 40-50 таблиц. Все Create Table скпипты выкладывать здесь смысла (и прав у меня) нет. Для ответа на мой вопрос думаю достаточно того, что я здесь выложил. Схема нормализована правильно. Вопрос в том, есть ли какие-нибудь best practices для таких случаев.